# Pointer initialization is overriding the value

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, new-operator

**Dog.h**

```
class Dog
{
public:
    int *pVal;
    Dog(int);
    ~Dog();
    static int GetVal(Dog d);
};
```

**Dog.cpp**

```
Dog::Dog(int val)
{
    pVal = new int;
    *pVal = val;
}

Dog::~Dog()
{
    delete pVal;
}

int Dog::GetVal(Dog d)
{
    return *(d.pVal);
}
```

**Test**

```
Dog fido(20);
CHECK(Dog::GetVal(fido) == 20);

Dog rex(21);
CHECK(Dog::GetVal(fido) == 20);
CHECK(Dog::GetVal(rex) == 21);
```

The first CHECK goes fine. However, as soon as I declare Dog rex(21), my fido object's pVal gets overridden by 21. By debugging, I have noticed that on calling **new int** in the constructor the pVal of **rex** gets the same memory address as the **fido** object's pVal. I tried a lot, but could not find anything.

What is the correct way of initializing the pointer and assigning the value to it?

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make this call:

```
Dog::GetVal(fido);
```

you make a *copy* of the `Dog` in the argument of `GetVal`. The default copy-constructor is invoked which only makes a shallow copy of `pVal`. So when the copy goes out of scope, the memory pointed at by `pVal` is deleted, which deletes the memory pointed at by `fido`.

One fix would be to take a `Dog&` in `GetVal`, which avoids a copy.

```
static int GetVal(Dog &d);
```

A better option would be to provide a copy-constructor for your `Dog`, like this:

```
Dog(Dog const & d) 
{ 
  pVal = new int{*(d.pVal)}; 
}
```

Here's a working [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/gIPPQ5).

As to your observation:

> I have noticed that on calling new int in the constructor the pVal of rex gets the same memory address as the fido object's pVal.

As mentioned above, by the time you call `rex`'s constructor, the memory allocated for `fido` has already been released, so that same memory can be used for `rex`. (This is not guaranteed to happen of course).

Comment: Yeah, I understood, the problem was causing in the GetVal. I did not understand that very well. Thank you.